# Recognize these white and gray ships?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

[image: photo of ships]

I want to get missing pieces but don't know Lego set number.

Answer (score 6):

The top ship looked like a Star Wars X-wing, and after a bit of searching it can be identified as [set 75218](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75218-1):

[image: set 75218]

Notably, the stickers in its sticker sheet match your photograph:

[image: sticker sheet]

---

Based on trans-blue 2x2 radar dish alone, the smaller ship can be identified as [set 8085 "Freeco Speeder"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8085-1):

[image: set 8085]